# jenkins pipeline sh returnStatus throws exception

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, sh, pipeline

I am trying to write a jenkins declarative pipeline code to execute a shell script and capture the exit status of the code. When I try executing, it throws an exception.

```
pipeline {
    stages {
        stage ('shcheck'){
            steps {
                echo 'Hello world - shcheck'
                status = sh(
                    returnStdout: true, 

                    script: '''#!/usr/bin/bash
                        echo 'testing sh'
                        exit 0
                    '''
                )

            }
        }

    }
}
```

On executing this, I get the following execption:

```
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[BFA] Scanning build for known causes...
[BFA] No failure causes found
[BFA] Done. 0s
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.jx.pipelines.dsl.PipelineDSLGlobal.getGlobalForName(PipelineDSLGlobal.java:114)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.jx.pipelines.dsl.JXPipelinesValidator.validateElement(JXPipelinesValidator.java:17)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.validator.DeclarativeValidatorContributor.validateElementAll(DeclarativeValidatorContributor.java:226)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.validator.DeclarativeValidatorContributor$validateElementAll$4.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.validator.DeclarativeValidatorContributor$validateElementAll$5.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.validator.ModelValidatorImpl$_validateFromContributors_closure43.doCall(ModelValidatorImpl.groovy:804)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor484.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.collect(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:3202)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.collect(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:3172)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$67.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:274)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.validator.ModelValidatorImpl.validateFromContributors(ModelValidatorImpl.groovy:801)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.validator.ModelValidatorImpl.this$2$validateFromContributors(ModelValidatorImpl.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor578.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:169)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.validator.ModelValidatorImpl.validateFromContributors(ModelValidatorImpl.groovy)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.validator.ModelValidatorImpl.this$2$validateFromContributors(ModelValidatorImpl.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor579.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:174)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.validator.ModelValidatorImpl.validateElement(ModelValidatorImpl.groovy:420)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ast.ModelASTStep.validate(ModelASTStep.java:70)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ast.ModelASTBranch.validate(ModelASTBranch.java:40)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ast.ModelASTStage.validate(ModelASTStage.java:141)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ast.ModelASTStages.validate(ModelASTStages.java:43)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ast.ModelASTStages.validate(ModelASTStages.java:37)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ast.ModelASTPipelineDef.validate(ModelASTPipelineDef.java:66)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ast.ModelASTPipelineDef$validate.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.parser.ModelParser.parsePipelineStep(ModelParser.groovy:264)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.parser.ModelParser.this$2$parsePipelineStep(ModelParser.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor982.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:174)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.parser.ModelParser.parse(ModelParser.groovy:162)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.parser.ModelParser$parse.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.parser.ModelParser.parse(ModelParser.groovy:129)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.parser.ModelParser.parse(ModelParser.groovy)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.parser.GroovyShellDecoratorImpl$1.call(GroovyShellDecoratorImpl.java:78)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1065)
Caused: BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'WorkflowScript' unexpected NullpointerException
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1070)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:603)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.lambda$doParse$0(CpsGroovyShell.java:135)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:136)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:132)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:127)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:560)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:521)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:320)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Finished: FAILURE
```

I expect that 0 is stored in '**status**' variable. I am not sure if I am missing any plugins or configuration settings.

I am a newbie to jenkins and any help would be appreciated.

Jenkins ver. 2.150.1

Answer (score 2):

Your pipeline has syntax errors that cause the validation failed.

1. missing `agent`
2. `status = sh ()` need to put inside `script`

Fixed code:

```
pipeline {
  agent any

  stages {

    stage ('shcheck'){
      steps {
        echo 'Hello world - shcheck'

        script {
          status = sh(
              returnStdout: true, 

              script: '''#!/usr/bin/bash
                  echo 'testing sh'
                  exit 0
              '''
          )
        }
      }
    }

  }
}
```